# Can't use clock_gettime() in VxWorks RTP application

Tags: clock, rtp, vxworks, gettime

Here's the code which is built into a static user library call log.a.  This builds fine.

```
#include <time.h>

void logSomething()  
{  
    ....  
    struct timespec tp;  
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);  
    timeStamp = tp;  
    //log some data with the timestamp  
    ...  
}
```

log.a is then linked with an RTP application which makes a call to logSomething().  When I build I get a link error due to "undefined reference to `clock_gettime(int, timespec*)'"

I am using VxWorks 6.9

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked on VxWorks, but you probably need to link your RTP application against log.a *and* the VxWorks library which contains the clock_gettime method. In Linux, that would be using `-lrt`.

Comment: The linker error sounds like time.h not being c++ safe if you compile this with a C++ compiler. Is there any difference if you rather do `extern "C" { #include <time.h> }`

Answer (score -2):

To debug, use this API in your RTP code and see if you are able to build without above errors.